# req.files is null if I pass data inside axios request (reactjs / nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make a user able to change his avatar (profile picture) on my website.
I'm using Reactjs with Axios on frontend and Express/Nodejs on backend (middleware: express-fileupload).

I need to send the `formdata` which will contain the image the user selected, and also I want to pass his `userid` and `username` on backend to be able to know who made this request.
If I pass the userid and username, the `req.files` is `null`, if I pass only the `formdata`, then `req.files` contains the images.

How can I send to backend the req.body (userid and username) and also the file (image) inside req.files?

My code (here `req.files` is `null`)

```js
async function uploadProfilePicture(e)
{
  const file = e.target.files[0];

  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file", file);

  const response = await Axios.post('/user/editavatar', {
    userid: 1,
    username: "Admin",
    formdata
  },
  {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
  }).then((response) => {
      return response.data;
  }).catch((error) => {
      return { error: error };
  });

  if(response.error)
  {
      return console.log(response.error);
  }
  
  console.log("Picture changed!");
  return true;
}
```

Here `req.files` is containing the image, but I don't have anymore `req.body.userid` and `req.body.username`

```js
async function uploadProfilePicture(e)
{
  const file = e.target.files[0];

  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file", file);

  const response = await Axios.post('/user/editavatar', formdata,
  {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
  }).then((response) => {
      return response.data;
  }).catch((error) => {
      return { error: error };
  });

  if(response.error)
  {
      return console.log(response.error);
  }
  
  console.log("Picture changed!");
  return true;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add non file values in formdata.
`filedata.append("userid", 1)` and etc...